# Is it possible to include Vue Admin (Bulma) into Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, vue-component, vue.js

I am pretty new to Vue.js and Js in general. I am using the Bulma.io CSS Framework and found the Vue-Admin Package which provides Vue Components in Bulma Styles.

I would like to use it but I am not sure how to require it. I tried to require a single Component like:

`javascript
// resource/assets/js/app.js
Vue.component('sidebar', require('../../../node_modules/vue-admin/client/components/layout/Sidebar.vue'));`

This throws the following Error in my Console:

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-admin/client/components/layout/Sidebar.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'scss-loader' in '/Volumes/Data/Entwicklung/Workspace/Private/TheNewSumoAndPanda/node_modules/vue-admin/client/components/layout'
 @ ./~/vue-admin/client/components/layout/Sidebar.vue 5:0-169
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js

ERROR in ./~/vue-bulma-expanding/src/Expanding.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'scss-loader' in '/Volumes/Data/Entwicklung/Workspace/Private/TheNewSumoAndPanda/node_modules/vue-bulma-expanding/src'
 @ ./~/vue-bulma-expanding/src/Expanding.vue 5:0-183
 @ ./~/buble-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./~/vue-admin/client/components/layout/Sidebar.vue
 @ ./~/vue-admin/client/components/layout/Sidebar.vue
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
```

I also tried to include some kind of an Autoloader and tried the following:

```
// resource/assets/js/app.js
require('../../../node_modules/vue-admin/client/app');
```

This throwed the following:

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-admin/client/app.js
Module parse failed: /Volumes/Data/Entwicklung/Workspace/Private/TheNewSumoAndPanda/node_modules/vue-admin/client/app.js Unexpected token (38:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   store,
|   nprogress,
|   ...App
| })
|
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js 9:0-53
```

This is the link to the Vue-Admin Package on GIthub:

https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin

I hope you guys can help me?

Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

I created an integration without laravel-mix: https://github.com/gazben/laravel-vue-admin

This solution uses the original build script, and the npm commands are wrapped by artisan commands. The output is symlinked to the appropriate directories.